# use existing spring, spring security, JPA backend in mobile application

Tags: mobile

I have one project (Web) in which I am using 
HTML,JSTL,JS .., JAVA, spring MVC, spring security, JPA and mySQL
Everything is working fine in this project.

Now my client is asking to create a mobile application (Android and IOS) for this project.
My question is:
What approach I should choose to use the same back end in my mobile application with minimal changes. 
I do not want to write all the stuff again for back end.

Can some one share any example as well. (may be a small demo or so).

Answer (score 0):

Its better you take advantage of web services here. RESTful webservices come with many handy features to address this issue saving us from re-writing the whole code for mobile applications.

We work for an eCommerce client, our mobile apps access the back end through apis which is primarily written in Oracle ATG Commerce. By this approach back end is completely decoupled from front end and this facilitates the view technology (web or mobile) to be independent. Our APIs are hosted on cloud container APIGEE. Soon, we are planning to dump the old jsp views in favor of Mustache templates to support responsive websites(unique view across all the devices).

Refer this page [Restful API for Mobility Solutions](https://dzone.com/articles/additional-considerations-when-working-on-native-m). It might give you a peripheral idea.